# PayPal Adaptive Payments Service 550001 Error

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have implemented a functionality into the admin panel where the admin can release the fund to seller (I am not sure but think this is what we called Adaptive Payments).

A buyer is paying some amount to the admin of application now the admin can release the funds to seller from the admin panel.

**All this is working perfect on sandbox**, but when I have updated the credentials to the live its showing me the error.

Here is my code.

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest();
/*
$receiver is
array:1 [▼
  0 => Receiver {#278 ▼
    +amount: 35.0
    +email: "me****p4@gmail.com"
    +phone: null
    +primary: null
    +invoiceId: null
    +paymentType: null
    +paymentSubType: null
    +accountId: null
  }
]
*/
$receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
$payRequest->receiverList = $receiverList;
$payRequest->senderEmail = "sender@email.com";

$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
$payRequest->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope;
$payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
$payRequest->currencyCode = $payment->currency_code;
$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = "http://replaceIpnUrl.com";

$sdkConfig = $this->config();
$adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService($sdkConfig);
$payResponse = $adaptivePaymentsService->Pay($payRequest);
```

**I am getting error 550001, here is the complete error:**

```
PayPal\Types\AP\PayResponse Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2017-06-05T05:16:36.032-07:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => b828f2378a7e
            [build] => 32250686
        )

    [payKey] => 
    [paymentExecStatus] => 
    [payErrorList] => 
    [paymentInfoList] => 
    [sender] => 
    [defaultFundingPlan] => 
    [warningDataList] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 550001
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly
                    [exceptionId] => 
                    [parameter] => 
                )
        )
)
```

I have searched a lot about this but did not get any clue. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: To check the current application access in your account. Go to [Manage App](https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications/manage)

Also checked You have tick mark box in application "Implicit payment".

If you find my comment helpful please let me know so I can write it in the answer section. 

Thank you,

Comment: Buddy the link you have provided to Manage the App is not working, please check that once at your end. And now when we go to the developer.paypal.com to manage the app it does not show any option for "Implicit Payment" http://prntscr.com/fpwbmb

Comment: With the few RnD I found that there are few permission allowed by the paypal itself. And for the functionality I am looking for we need the "payout" permission and it is not by default allowed on live (https://prnt.sc/fpwccw) and I am unable to find the solution for this. And paypal support is really very bad I am not getting any help from the officials now I think I will have to change the payment gateway to Stripe or any another one :(

Comment: What happens when you click on enable button for payout?

Comment: it just show a contact button and that redirects me to self help (https://www.paypal.com/gb/selfhelp/home)

Comment: and I also posted the same question there as well, but the worst paypal support :( https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Getting-started/Unable-to-release-payment-from-my-paypal-account/m-p/1228798#M13902

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to your application does not include the implicit payment. As far as I knew, PayPal does not supported for the implicit payment for the new application. Check you App ID again to confirm which application has been granted to your account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I am new in paypal implementation can you please guid me how can I check this thing. I have created the app on the paypal and get the app id from there